# Allegro Selenium find and click button

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, google-colaboratory

stack:
google colab,
python,
selenium,
BeautifulSoup

I would like to get the contact details of the seller.The data becomes visible when you click the "pokaż" button.
how do i find and click this button?

```
<div><div class="_31b2a_2D760"><span class="_kz8jr _31b2a_5mXDa _31b2a_1L727"></span><ul class="_17qy1 _1rj80 _1sql3 _3a4zn"><li><a data-box-name="AskSellerClick" class="_w7z6o" href="#zadaj-pytanie" rel="nofollow">pytanie do sprzedającego</a></li><li><div>dra****@************<!-- --> (<button data-box-name="SellerEmailShow" class="_w7z6o _ypulx" type="button">pokaż</button>)</div></li></ul></div><div class="_31b2a_2D760"><span class="_kz8jr _31b2a_5mXDa _31b2a_14F6t"></span><ul class="_17qy1 _1rj80 _1sql3 _3a4zn"><li><div>+48 ** *** ** **<!-- --> (<button data-box-name="SellerMobileShow" class="_w7z6o _ypulx" type="button">pokaż</button>)</div></li><li><div>+48 *** *** ***<!-- --> (<button data-box-name="SellerMobileShow" class="_w7z6o _ypulx" type="button">pokaż</button>)</div></li></ul></div></div>
```

my code:

```
!apt update
!apt install chromium-chromedriver
!pip install selenium

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

wd = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
wd.get('https://allegro.pl/oferta/zageszczarka-6-5km-90kg-higher-briggs-gratisy-9003885105#aboutSeller')

click_on_button = wd.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div[10]/div/div/div/div/div[7]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/section/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/section[2]/div/div/div[2]/ul/li[1]/div/button')
click_on_button.click()                   

soup = BeautifulSoup(wd.page_source, 'html.parser')
dd = soup.find_all('ul', attrs={'class':'_17qy1 _1rj80 _1sql3 _3a4zn'})

print(dd)
```

Message:

```
ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <button data-box-name="SellerMobileShow" class="_w7z6o _ypulx" type="button">...</button> is not clickable at point (597, 537). Other element would receive the click: <div class="_9f0v0 _jkrtd mpof_ki_s" slot="button">...</div>
  (Session info: headless chrome=87.0.4280.66)
```

How else can I find these buttons? Unfortunately, the Xpath changes when the seller changes. Below are 3 examples of Xpath from 3 different sellers:

```
/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div[10]/div/div/div/div/div[6]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/section/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/section[2]/div/div/div[1]/ul/li[2]/div/button

/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div[10]/div/div/div/div/div[4]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/section/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/section[2]/div/div/div[1]/ul/li[2]/div/button

/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div[10]/div/div/div/div/div[7]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/section/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/section[2]/div/div/div[1]/ul/li[2]/div/button
```

Message:

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div[10]/div/div/div/div/div[7]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/section/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/section[2]/div/div/div[1]/ul/li[2]/div/button"}
  (Session info: headless chrome=87.0.4280.66)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a pop up window when first time load the  web site. You need to close this pop up window then its work.

```
wd = webdriver.Chrome()
wd.get('https://allegro.pl/oferta/zageszczarka-6-5km-90kg-higher-briggs-gratisy-9003885105#aboutSeller')

wd.maximize_window()
wd.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[5]/div/div[2]/div[2]/button[1]").click()

click_on_button = wd.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div[10]/div/div/div/div/div[7]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/section/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/section[2]/div/div/div[1]/ul/li[2]/div/button')
click_on_button.click()
click_on_button = wd.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div[10]/div/div/div/div/div[7]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/section/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/section[2]/div/div/div[2]/ul/li[1]/div/button')
click_on_button.click()
click_on_button = wd.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div[10]/div/div/div/div/div[7]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/section/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/section[2]/div/div/div[2]/ul/li[2]/div/button')
click_on_button.click()
```

Comment: hi @samsulislam
When you change the link to the auction, the Xpath to the "pokaż" button changes. How else can I find and click these elements?
The solutions below did not work:

lick_on_button = wd.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, 'pokaż')
click_on_button.click()
lick_on_button = wd.find_element(By.NAME, '_w7z6o _ypulx')
click_on_button.click()

Comment: @dominik tu masz selektory '[data-box-name='SellerEmailShow']' [data-box-name='SellerEmailClick'] [data-analytics-click-value='sellerLogin'] samego pokaz sprzedawce nie musisz robic, wystarczy do adresu dodac #aboutSeller - to otworzy ten panel